# Cassandra: How do CAST a text column to a numeric?

Tags: cassandra

Title:  "Support type casting in selection clause"

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10310

This JIRA issue is RESOLVED, but I cannot find any "cast()" capability in CQL.

I am using the latest version of DevCenter (1.6).

Can somebody describe how to select a text column and cast it to a number in Cassandra?

EDIT:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
  id text, 
  value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE CUSTOM INDEX my_data_idx ON my_data (value) 
USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex';
```

The following just says "Unknown CQL3 function cast" in the DevCenter 1.6 CQL Editor.

```
select cast(value as double) from my_data;
```

Comment: Which Cassandra (not DevCenter) version you're running your query against? What's the query + schema of the CF you're running the query against? What's the error message?

Comment: Cassandra 3.7 is the version

Comment: With DevCenter 1.6, Cassandra 3.7 and your schema I get `InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid call to function system.castAsDouble, none of its type signatures match (known type signatures: system.castAsDouble : (smallint) -> double, system.castAsDouble : (int) -> double, system.castAsDouble : (varint) -> double, system.castAsDouble : (tinyint) -> double, system.castAsDouble : (decimal) -> double, system.castAsDouble : (float) -> double, system.castAsDouble : (counter) -> double, system.castAsDouble : (bigint) -> double)"`

Comment: I added another column of data type 'int'.  When I run the query against that column, the "cast" works!  Two things:  cast(text) does not exist, but cast(int) does work.  Second, the DevCenter IDE says "cast" is "Unknown", but when I run it, it works!!!

Comment: [This comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10310?focusedCommentId=14996341&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14996341) from the CASSANDRA-10310 ticket lists what casts are supported.